# Is it possible to cascade active record deletion in batches?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, cascade

I have a lot of data I want to delete, and for this reason I use delete/delete_all instead of destroy, via cascade on the foreign keys (`on_delete: :cascade`).

I want to delete one parent active record which has a couple of "child tables" with many rows. Some of these child tables also have a couple of child tables. For this reason I have added cascade on the foreign keys, such that I only need to call parent.delete to trigger the deletion of all children and grand children of parent.

I want to combine delete/delete_all with active record batches https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html, but as there is only one single parent, I am not sure how to combine batches and cascade delete in a neat way.

One option would be to explicitly batch delete the children and grand children, e.g.

```
parent.children_x.find_each do |child_x|
  child_x.grand_children_y.in_batches do |grand_child_y_batch|
    grand_child_y_batch.delete_all        
  end
  child_x.delete        
end
parent.children_z.in_batches do |child_batch|
  child_batch.delete_all
end
...etc...
```

but if there is a more implicit way that allows me to only call delete on the parent and batch delete the children and grand children, that would be preferrable, e.g.

```
parent.cascade_in_batches do |parent_batch|
  parent_batch.delete_all #This batch deletes all children and grand children
end
```

I see that there is no `in_batches` on parent as the parent is only a single entity, so it looks like it is only possible if I explicitly delete in batches as in the first example above?

Thanks,

-Louise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really just need to setup the foreign keys to cascade and Postgres will take care of deleting all the way down the line. Since this is implemented on the database layer it does not matter how you trigger the delete from Rails.

```
class CreateCountries < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :countries do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateStates < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :states do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.belongs_to :country, null: false, foreign_key: {on_delete: :cascade}
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateCities < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :cities do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.belongs_to :state, null: false, foreign_key: {on_delete: :cascade}
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Models:

```
class Country < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :states
  has_many :cities, through: :states
end

class State < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :cities
end

class City < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :state
  has_one :country, through: :state
end
```

Passing spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Country, type: :model do
  describe "cascading delete" do
    let!(:country){ Country.create }
    let!(:state){ country.states.create }
    let!(:city){ state.cities.create }

    it "deletes the states" do
      expect {
        country.delete
      }.to change(State, :count).from(1).to(0)
    end

    it "deletes the cities" do
      expect {
        Country.delete_all
      }.to change(City, :count).from(1).to(0)
    end
  end
end
```

If you are using `.each_with_batches` or not here is kind of irrelevant here. Anything that creates a `DELETE FROM countries` query is going to fire that database trigger. Unless you really need to evaluate if each parent should be deleted in Rails you should just be able to do:

```
Country.where(evil: true).delete_all
```

This is going to be far more efficient then `.find_each` as you're just doing one SQL query. If you iterate through the records you're doing one `DELETE FROM coutries WHERE id = ?` query per row and since its blocking Rails has to wait for the round trip to the db.

Comment: Ah ok - so just to make sure I understand: the cascade delete triggered by parent.delete will generate one SQL delete statement for each table, child- and grand parent table á la "DELETE FROM X where <foreign_key> in (...)", which means there is no need for the batches features in this scenario? As you write, there would only be a need for the batches features if you want to use destroy or if you want to do some logic using the objects to determine whether the object should be deleted or not?

Comment: No - you still don't get it. In the example in the spec when you call `country.delete` the query is just `DELETE FROM countries WHERE countries.id = ?;`. If you call Country.delete_all its the same query but with no `WHERE` clause. The cascade is purely done on the DB side - Rails does not know it exists. When you create that delete query Postgres knows that there is a foreign key constraint that points to the countries table.

Comment: When that foreign key is set to `ON DELETE CASCADE` postgres will automatically delete the rows on states and since cities also has a foreign key constraint (on states) those rows are also removed. Think of it like a DB trigger that runs before you delete the row so that referential integrity is maintained.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks a lot. I see the active record batches examples include an example with in_batches and delete_all:

`Person.where("age > 21").in_batches do |relation|
  relation.delete_all
  sleep(10) # Throttle the delete queries
end`

 Wouldn't that example be less efficient than doing Person.where("age > 21").delete_all directly, as the code without in_batches uses only one SQL query? If so, what's the point of the example - to provide non-blocking periods during a time-consuming delete?

Comment: Yes it's less effective. I guess there is could be some rare scenario where you have millions of rows and wanted to do it that way but I think it's mostly a contived example.

Comment: A delete does not lock the entire table. It only locks the row currently being deleted afaik.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer.